# How do i get the desired result from multiple table as follow

Tags: sql, left-join

Here is three tables
Table: Vehicle Types

```
VehTypID    Name 
1   Car
2   Public Bus
3   Ambulance
4   Trucks
5   Auto
```

Table: Services

```
VehTypID    Name 
1   Towing Alert 
1   Over Speed Alert
3   Location 
4   Odo Meter
4   Speed Limit
4   Fuel Limit
4   SOS
4   Emergency Control
```

Table: NotificationAndReports

```
VehTypID    Name 
1   Popup
1   Email 
1   SMS
1   WhatsApp
2   Digital Status
4   Email Reports
4   Daily Summary Reports
4   Live Tracking
```

and the expected result is 
Expected Results

```
Vehicle Types   Services             NotificationAndReports
Car             Towing Alert         Popup
null            Over Speed Alert     Email 
null            null                 SMS
null            null                 WhatsApp
Public Bus      null                 Digital Status
Ambulance       Location             null
Trucks          Odo Meter            Email Reports
null            Speed Limit          Daily Summary Reports
null            Fuel Limit           Live Tracking
null            SOS                  null
null            Emergency Control    null
Auto            null                 null
```

i m using left join to get the data but instead of giving above result it returns multiple values.

Comment: Why would you want so many null values in your expected results? Did you intend for that?

Comment: Your expected results are not in a relational format because they depend on the ordering of the rows (that is, a given row may not mean anything independent of the rows around it).  Hence, you should do this in the application layer.

Comment: Hi. It is not obvious from the example how your output is a function of input. Explain in words clearly exactly the condition for when some row (v,s,n) is in the output and if the order matters explain that too.  Please also read & act on [mcve]. One of the answers has already helped with that but code each code question should come with one. PS Is this a certain join of the three tables ordered in a certain way and then with each entry that is the same as the entry above it replaced by null? Is it a sequence of (per vehicle) row groups where each group is some side by side vertical lists?

Comment: What DBMS? (Plus the rest of a [mcve] please.) Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. This is just asking for us to do your work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
CREATE TABLE #VehicleTypes(
VehTypID    BIGINT,
Name NVARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO #VehicleTypes
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 1  as bbbb ,'Car'                    as aaaa union all
SELECT 2  as bbbb,'Public Bus'              as aaaa union all
select 3  as bbbb, 'Ambulance'              as aaaa union all
select 4  as bbbb, 'Trucks'             as aaaa union all
select 5  as bbbb, 'Auto'                   as aaaa ) AS a


CREATE TABLE #Services 
(
VehTypID    BIGINT,
Name NVARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO #Services
SELECT * FROM (
select 1 as bbbb,  'Towing Alert'                       as aaaa    union all 
select 1 as bbbb,  'Over Speed Alert'                   as aaaa    union all
select 3 as bbbb,  'Location'                           as aaaa    union all
select 4 as bbbb,  'Odo Meter'                          as aaaa    union all
select 4 as bbbb,  'Speed Limit'                        as aaaa    union all
select 4 as bbbb,  'Fuel Limit'                     as aaaa    union all
select 4 as bbbb,  'SOS'                                as aaaa    union all
select 4 as bbbb,  'Emergency CONTROL'                  as aaaa    ) AS a

CREATE TABLE #NotificationAndReports
(
VehTypID    BIGINT,
Name NVARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO #NotificationAndReports
SELECT * FROM (
select 1 as bbbb ,  'Popup'                         as aaaa     union all
select 1 as bbbb ,  'Email'                         as aaaa     union all
select 1 as bbbb ,  'SMS'                           as aaaa     union all
select 1 as bbbb ,  'WhatsApp'                      as aaaa     union all
select 2 as bbbb ,  'Digital Status'                as aaaa     union all
select 4 as bbbb ,  'Email Reports'                 as aaaa     union all
select 4 as bbbb ,  'Daily Summary Reports'         as aaaa     union all
select 4 as bbbb ,  'Live Tracking'                 as aaaa     ) AS a






SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 )) AS rno,  ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 )) AS PrntID,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY #Services.Name ORDER BY ( SELECT 1 ))  AS ChildRn,
#VehicleTypes.Name AS  VehicleTypes,#Services.Name AS Services,#NotificationAndReports.Name AS NotificationAndReports
INTO #temp
FROM #VehicleTypes
  RIGHT JOIN #Services
        ON #Services.VehTypID = #VehicleTypes.VehTypID
  LEFT JOIN #NotificationAndReports
        ON #NotificationAndReports.VehTypID = #VehicleTypes.VehTypID 
        ORDER BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID


SELECT CASE WHEN PrntID = 1 THEN VehicleTypes ELSE NULL END AS VehicleTypes,CASE WHEN ChildRn = 1 THEN Services ELSE NULL END AS Services,NotificationAndReports
 FROM #temp ORDER BY rno


DROP TABLE #NotificationAndReports,#Services,#VehicleTypes,#temp`
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this outputs what the user wants for the general case & what that is. Please don't just dump code. Also you use DBMS-specific features. Comment for clarification, don't answer unclear questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get rid of multiple values in your results. Because of relational databases which use "relations". Imagine you get rid of duplicates, but then for example expected row

```
"null, null, SMS"
```

doesn't have any reference to Types or Services. You can probably check the previous row, but in relational databases, each row has to have all the information because rows are equal and order of row shouldn't affect the result (In terms of Relational Algebra).

But if you are using the database which supports **[arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html)** (like Postgresql) you can flatten your query with arrays. With SQL like this

```
select t.Name, 
(select array(select s.Name from Services as s where s.VehTypID = t.VehTypID)) as "Services",
(select array(select r.Name from Reports as r where r.VehTypID = t.VehTypID)) as "Reports"
from Types as t
```

You'll get the result like this

```
| name       | Services                                               | Reports                                           |
| ---------- | ------------------------------------------------------ | ------------------------------------------------- |
| Car        | Towing Alert,Over Speed Alert                          | Popup,Email,SMS,WhatsApp                          |
| Public Bus |                                                        | Digital Status                                    |
| Ambulance  | Location                                               |                                                   |
| Trucks     | Odo Meter,Speed Limit,Fuel Limit,SOS,Emergency Control | Email Reports,Daily Summary Reports,Live Tracking |
| Auto       |                                                        |                                                   |
```

See [www.db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6NDmc6uQHs9jcAieLQR9Cc/0)

Comment: It's possible to use ordering etc to produce an SQL result set that is the appropriate function of input and/or your grouping with lists. (I'm not saying one *should* write such function in SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Works In Microsoft SQL Server */
CREATE TABLE #VehicleTypes
        (
            VehTypID BIGINT ,
            Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
        );
    INSERT INTO #VehicleTypes
                SELECT  *
                FROM    (
                            SELECT  1 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Car' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  2 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Public Bus' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  3 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Ambulance' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Trucks' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  5 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Auto' AS aaaa
                        ) AS a;


    CREATE TABLE #Services
        (
            VehTypID BIGINT ,
            Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
        );

    INSERT INTO #Services
                SELECT  *
                FROM    (
                            SELECT  1 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Towing Alert' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  1 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Over Speed Alert' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  3 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Location' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Odo Meter' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Speed Limit' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Fuel Limit' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'SOS' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Emergency CONTROL' AS aaaa
                        ) AS a;

    CREATE TABLE #NotificationAndReports
        (
            VehTypID BIGINT ,
            Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
        );
    INSERT INTO #NotificationAndReports
                SELECT  *
                FROM    (
                            SELECT  1 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Popup' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  1 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Email' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  1 AS bbbb ,
                                    'SMS' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  1 AS bbbb ,
                                    'WhatsApp' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  2 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Digital Status' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Email Reports' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Daily Summary Reports' AS aaaa
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  4 AS bbbb ,
                                    'Live Tracking' AS aaaa
                        ) AS a;




    /*Way 1 */
    SELECT  CASE WHEN LAG(#VehicleTypes.Name, 1, 0) OVER ( ORDER BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID ) = '0'
                      OR LAG(#VehicleTypes.Name, 1, 0) OVER ( ORDER BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID ) <> #VehicleTypes.Name THEN
                     #VehicleTypes.Name
                 ELSE NULL
            END AS VehicleName ,
            CASE WHEN LAG(#Services.Name, 1, 0) OVER ( ORDER BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID ) = '0'
                      OR LAG(#Services.Name, 1, 0) OVER ( ORDER BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID ) <> #Services.Name THEN
                     #Services.Name
                 ELSE NULL
            END AS ServicesName ,
            #VehicleTypes.VehTypID ,
            #Services.VehTypID ,
            #NotificationAndReports.VehTypID ,
            #NotificationAndReports.Name
    FROM    #VehicleTypes
            RIGHT JOIN #Services ON #Services.VehTypID = #VehicleTypes.VehTypID
            LEFT JOIN #NotificationAndReports ON #NotificationAndReports.VehTypID = #VehicleTypes.VehTypID;

    /*Way 2 */
    SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY #VehicleTypes.Name
                                          ORDER BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID
                                        ) = 1 THEN #VehicleTypes.Name
                 ELSE NULL
            END AS VehicleName ,
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY #Services.Name
                                          ORDER BY #VehicleTypes.VehTypID
                                        ) = 1 THEN #Services.Name
                 ELSE NULL
            END AS ServicesName ,
            #VehicleTypes.VehTypID ,
            #Services.VehTypID ,
            #NotificationAndReports.VehTypID ,
            #NotificationAndReports.Name
    FROM    #VehicleTypes
            RIGHT JOIN #Services ON #Services.VehTypID = #VehicleTypes.VehTypID
            LEFT JOIN #NotificationAndReports ON #NotificationAndReports.VehTypID = #VehicleTypes.VehTypID;



    DROP TABLE #VehicleTypes ,
               #NotificationAndReports ,
               #Services;
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this outputs what the user wants for the general case & what that is. Please don't just dump code. Also you use DBMS-specific features. Comment for clarification, don't answer unclear questions.